# Issue of random indent error in VScode integrated terminal

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code, indentation

When trying to *run selected lines of code in Integrated Terminal*, I randomly get "IndentationError: unexpected indent". The same code executes perfectly in the OSX terminal, but fails 75% of the time in the integrated terminal. The error is happening to different lines, and happens mostly within functions.

However, when I try to run functions batch by batch, it seems to work. I've tried pep8, flake8, pylint, manually indenting with 4 spaces, the autoindent. It seems that the error is coming from VSCode since I can reproduce when disabling Microsft Python and Don Jayamanne Python Extension.

There have been many updates since I started using VSCode but here is the current set-up:

```
macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
VSCode Version 1.22.1 (1.22.1)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
```

My workspace settings are as follow:

```
{// PythonVSCode extensions
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
// Terminal
"terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "underline",
"terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
// Editor
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 1000,
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 0,
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.autoIndent": false,
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#727a81",
},
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on"
},
}
```

Comment: If you ask one question at a time about your IDE, this would be an okay question.  Just remove one of the questions embedded here and I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Done, first time on stackoverflow sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the module information is entirely germane to your question, but you did mention that there was a module causing issues, so I'll leave it in for now...

Comment: Can you provide a sample bit of syntax? And is this on the standard Python REPL or IPython? (And a GIF showing what's happening would be awesome!)

Comment: Did you by any chance use the Jupyter extension? I came across the same error couple days back, I think the #%% code lense syntax was not recognized if you try to run it in the normal terminal.